# how can i add inline javascripts to navigation template in Google App Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to develop a navigational menu being referenced to different pages in my app.
am using Materialize css as a ui and placed the nav codes in a separate file

```
        <div id="navigation">
    <nav>
      <div class="nav-wrapper blue darken-3">
        <div class="container">
          <a href="#" class="brand-logo">
          <a href="#" class="sidenav-trigger" data-target="sideMobile"> <i class="material-icons">menu</i> </a>      
          <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li>          
              <a href="<?= getbaseUrl(); ?> "  class=" waves-effect waves-light" type="button"  >Incoming Stock</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="page.html">Components</a></li>
            <li><a href="page.html">Javascript</a></li>
            <li><a href="page.html">Mobile</a></li>
          </ul>

        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <ul class="sidenav  blue lighten-2" id="sideMobile">
      <div class="container">
        <li><a href="page.html">Sass</a></li>
        <li><a href="page.html">Components</a></li>
        <li><a href="page.html">Javascript</a></li>
        <li><a href="page.html">Mobile</a></li>
      </div>
    </ul> 
    </div>
```

which is being reference in the different pages as

```
<?!= include("navBar"); ?>
```

in the `<head>` part of the code.

function include() is in the serverside code as

```
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}
```

in the doGet part of the app, page is being rendered by

```
return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("home").evaluate();
```

how can i get to write inline codes in the navBar page? when rendered, all javascript are being displayed as encoded html.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating an `HtmlOutput`, you should create an `HtmlTemplate` object and `evaluate` it.

Reference: [Class HtmlTemplate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-template)

> A template object for dynamically constructing HTML.

```js
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(filename).evaluate().getContent();
}
```